Violating the Single Responsibility Principle?
We are creating a one-to-many relationship in a class, for example, a student can have many books.
In this class, are we not breaking the Single Responsibility Principle?
Because Student class has its own business logic. Moreover it would also have logic to add and remove books.
Similarly the Student can have many EnrolledSubjects, too.
I have a working system with a Student class that has relationships with Books and EnrolledSubjects. But I think it is violation the SRP.

As a beginner, I'd counter-intuitively encourage you to break all those rules at least once. (Only if it's not for a production project, of course) Imho that's the best way to learn how they came to be and what they mean. And when to ignore them.

@Fildor If the code works fine when a principle is broken... Is it ok to ignore it? Is it possible that it may lead to issues in later stages in maintenance?

All of the above: yes. There is no "clean code police". Just always ask yourself: "Will the future user24437316 hate me for this?"

The Student class should have a property Books that is a collection type, e.g. List<Book>. All the functionality for adding, removing, etc, books from a student is in that collection type, not in the Student class, so there's no violation of the SRP.

It may be a good idea to read the literature associated with the SOLID principles, as there's more to each principle than what is implied by each name. For instance, in APPP Robert C. Martin defines the Single Responsibility Principle (SRP) as:

A class should have only one reason to change.

and then proceeds to describe the design principle over an entire book chapter.
This is a design ideal that requires some experience with software design, and even practitioners with decades of experience can't expect to hit it on the nail every time. Rather, as a software architect, you try to think through whether or not a particular design could be reasonably be expected to have more than one reason to change.
For instance, in your current design, a student may have many books. Clearly, you may have some code that implements this design choice, e.g. a class field
private readonly List<Book> books;

and perhaps some methods that allow client code to add and remove books to the student:
public void AddBook(Book book)
{
    books.Add(book);
}

Do you expect this code to change? If so, that should be the Student class' single responsibility. If you don't expect this code to change, then, from an SRP perspective, this code is 'free', and you may designate some other behaviour of the class as its single responsibility.
Things to look out for when it comes to reasons to change are often business logic, UI requirements, storage (e.g. database) formats, etc. At a coarse level, one point of the SRP is that you shouldn't, for example, mix business logic with UI rendering, since these concerns indicate more than one reason to change. Rather, you may have a Student class which implements any business logic associated with students, and then a separate StudentView, StudentWriter, or StudentRenderer that takes care of UI concerns.

I have a small doubt. For Example Storage Requirements could change. From being noSQL to SQL. Or the Ui from desktop application to a website. What does it mean when we say Business Logic can be changed? Does that mean adding new logic?

"A change" means "different than before". Additional logic may or may not constitute a change depending on the scope you are looking at. That's what makes those principles so hard to understand and apply.

Exactly... It's confusing for beginners.
If I say, I want to store the books data in dictionaries later (currently it is in list), will this be considered a change?

That's a change of an implementation detail but on a higher level, the student still has 0 or more books.

@user24437316 If you truly believe that you may later need to change how you keep track of books, then you should design with that in mind. One option is to design such that the 'collection' data structure is the reason to change, but this doesn't sound particularly realistic. Another option is to apply the Open/Closed Principle and design the class in such a way that you can replace one 'collection' data structure with another without changing Student. The SOLID principles interweave; it's usually futile trying to understand one isolated from the other principles.
